# How to auto-generate database schema using DataNucleus for Google Cloud SQL on localhost and AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, datanucleus

I'm migrating my webapp to Google AppEngine. I worked with Hibernate previously. Since AppEngine works with DataNucleus, which is new to me, I'm facing problems with generating database schema. How do I achieve this? In hibernate, I used to do it with the property `hbm2ddl.auto` in hibernate.cfg.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When learning something new its normal to [look at the documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/schema.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Next time I'll make sure I've read the documentation thoroughly before asking. :)